# write secrets to vault using python hvac

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault

using client.write does not help writing the secrets to database backend suported by postgresql in vault using python hvac. what method/function should I be using.

```
import os
import hvac
from vault_psycopg2 import vault

client = hvac.Client(url=os.environ['VAULT_URL'], token=os.environ['VAULT_TOKEN'])
client.read('dbs/creds/readonly/')
```

Thats the code for reading, but how to I write to create a role based access pointing to postgres DB through vault.

On vault command line in docker I usually run this to create role and a password for it.

```
vault write dbs/roles/readonly\
  db_name=postgres \
  creation_statements="CREATE ROLE \"{{name}}\" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}'; GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO \"{{name}}\";" \
  default_ttl="1h" \
  max_ttl="24h"
Success! Data written to: dbs/roles/readonly
```

Comment: I was able to read the secret becasue its easy to just use client.read to read from a path. But I want to programatically generate the secret like I would do from vault command line in python and then read that secret to make a connection to postgresql DB. I was able to generate secret manually and then later used hvac client.read in python to get username and pwd and passed it on to postgres connection to talk to the DB.

How do I generate this secret? WHat method should be called.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever figured this out, but you need something like:

```
client.write("database/roles/readonly", db_name='postgres', 
             creation_statements="CREATE ROLE \"{{name}}\" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}'; GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO \"{{name}}\";",
             default_ttl="1h", max_ttl="24hr")
```

to create the role definition in vault.

Then, to actually create the postgres user/role and get credentials, you need to use

```
response = client.read("database/roles/readonly")
username = response.get("data").get("username")
password = response.get("data").get("password")
```